# rearranging UIButtons while orientation changes in iphone?

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uibutton, position

enter image description herehai, i have a list of buttons in a view which is a sub view of another UIView. i need to rearrange  these buttons in order while the device orientation changes to landscape mode.

is their any way to do this? or else i need to do all these things manually by repositioning all buttons?

Comment: see [this question for a general discussion of this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621777/how-to-properly-design-multi-orientation-ipad-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CGFrame of you buttons in the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterFaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        Button1.frame=...;
        Button2.frame=....;
     }
     else if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterFaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
       Button1.frame=...;
        Button2.frame=....;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is for letting your view controller specify **which** orientations to support.  It's not really for handling the rotation.  You also have to return either `YES` or `NO` in that method.  You don't have a return value at all.

Comment: @Nate: Yes, you are half right..we can also specify the coordinates for each orientation in this method.

Comment: No, I'm completely right.  That method is for exactly what I said it's for.  `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is for handling the change, once it's decided that there will be the change.  You don't even test for whether the rotation is going to be supported, which is **the point** of that method (hence, the return value).

Comment: Ok i got whatever you wanted to say...and my edited my answer as per your needs..

Answer (score 3):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, mentioned in the other answers, is for letting your view controller decide **whether or not** to allow autorotation to a given orientation. (you're supposed to return `YES` or `NO`).

If you really want to **programmatically** adjust layout of your subviews, you would do it in either

```objc
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                          delay: 0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations: ^(void) {

                         if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
                             self.button.frame = CGRectMake(x1, y1, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);
                         } else {
                             self.button.frame = CGRectMake(x2, y2, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);
                         }

                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                         // code to run after animation completes can go here
                     }];
}
```

or, you can use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` for one-step rotations.

Not only is it only called when the autorotation **actually** happens, but it gives you the `duration` of the animation.  This allows you to wrap any animatable view property changes inside your own animation, so that they smoothly animate during the rotation, instead of just snapping to their new values.

But, really, this is *usually* not the best way to solve the problem.  See [this link for a more general discussion of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621777/how-to-properly-design-multi-orientation-ipad-application)

Answer (score 0):

1-you can use this

```
YOUR_OBJECT.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

OR

2- use frame property with CGRectMake for your object in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
   if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterFaceOrientationPortrait)
else if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterFaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it via

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method.

Make two methods in your `viewController.h` class assume they are -

```
-(void)viewForPortraitMode;
-(void)viewForLandscapeMode;
```

And this is the body part of both in your `viewcontroller.m` file.

```
//Set frame according to you
-(void)viewForPortraitMode
{
    [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(117.0, 383.0, 87.0, 37.0)];
    [btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 240.0, 324.0)];
}

-(void)viewForLandscapeMode
{
    [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(200.0, 252, 87.0, 37.0)];
    [btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 7.0, 446.0, 228.0)];
}
```

And call these two methods in this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self viewForPortraitMode];
    }
    else
    {
        [self viewForLandscapeMode];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: but he view is not updating automatically. it need to close the view and reopen for the updation