# Recreating the iPad home screen icon rotation / orientation effect

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, orientation

I am creating a grid of icons in Objective C / Xcode.

Is there anyway to re-create the iPad Home screen, the one filled with a grid of icons for each App you have on your iPad.

What I am most interested in is reproducing the effect on the icons when the device is rotated. On rotation, a new grid icons (which matches the new orientation) swings around to the right orientation, and the icons themselves transform (I'm guessing its an alpha fade from one icon to the other) into the new icon that would appear at that position.

Ive looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721494/rearranging-uibuttons-while-orientation-changes-in-iphone), and also at [this blog](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/designing_ios_apps_for_interface). But I am wondering if there is a class (hopefully one developed by Apple, but third party solutions will do) which recreates this effect?

If there isn't such a class, can anyone suggest to me how I would do the icon transformation effect whilst the screen is swinging around to the correct orientation?

Comment: If you're supporting iOS 6 and up, you're in luck: [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @architectpianist This is what I went with in the end. Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 offers a class called `UICollectionView` that handles the creation of these grids for you. The API is fairly similar to that of `UITableView` and allows you lots of control for customization.

Check out the [UICollectionView class reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=ccUkUs2TF7C1sASLmoCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cWc), as well as [this introductory tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uicollectionview-layouts/).