# support all orientations xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, orientation

I have created all my views programmatically, nothing with IB. My views contain navigation controller, table views, buttons, tab bar. Now how should i make my app to support all the orientations for iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: Go through the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621777/how-to-properly-design-multi-orientation-ipad-application

Answer (score 0):

Write this in all your `UIViewController`-s:

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting device orientations supported in Summary pane of Project's Target like in the picture attached?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed in iOS 6:

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```